# Sympy symbol and the cls parameter

Tags: sympy, symbolic-computation, finite-field

I have seen f = sympy.symbols('f', cls=Function) but not any documentation. Python does not like x = sympy.symbols('x', cls=FF(8)), it complains about

raise CoercionFailed("expected an integer, got %s" % a) CoercionFailed: expected an integer, got x

Whan is the purpose of the cls parameters and what must I do so that cls=FF(8) is meaning full?

With x = sympy.symbols('x', cls=FF(8)) I want x to be a symbol in the field FF(8), i.e x^(2^8-1) must give me 1.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here:

- The `FF` object does not allow Symbols. It only works for exact numerical entries, like `FF(3)(2)`.
- Therefore, the `cls` parameter of `symbols` will not work. That just changes what object is used to create the symbol, so it must take a string as an input (the default is `Symbol`).
- SymPy does not currently support Symbols over finite fields. The best bet you can get is to use the `Poly` object with the `modulus` flag.
- `FF` currently only supports finite fields of prime cardinality. `FF(8)` has actually created the ring Z_8, not the finite field with 8 elements.
- You probably know this, but `^` does not do exponentiation in SymPy/Python. Use `**`.

Comment: I also work in sage and there '^' is the exponent, at least I thought so until now. I created a python class which I executed in sage when '^' was not the exponent by had to use '**'. Why does sage not see '^' as the exponent in when used in a class?

That is the purpose of the string passed to symbols with the cls parameter?

Comment: Yeah, Sage doesn't override `__xor__` to use `^` because that won't work (`^` has a different precedence than `**`). Rather, it parses the user input to wrap integer literals and replace `^` with `**`. But I guess whatever you were using was not preparsed by sage.

Comment: The parsing will explain.
How easy will it be to expand the usage of the cls parameter to be able to give it a name of sage finite field class, so that the variable given by sympy.Symsbols will be in the finite field.